# Javascript or jQuery - Replacing (' with (\' and ') with \')

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I was trying to replace this `('` with `(\'` and `')` with `\')` My attempts were few as I'm not comfortable with **RegExp**.

What I tried was `myText.replace(/\(\'/g, "(\')");` and `myText.replace(/\'\)/g, "\')");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not your regex but your replacement. You need to escape the backslash, otherwise it (unnecessarily) escapes the `'`:

```
myText = myText.replace(/\('/g, "(\\'");
myText = myText.replace(/'\)/g, "\\')");
```

With some slightly more advanced techniques (namely a capturing group and a lookahead) you can combine these into one regex:

```
myText = myText.replace(/(\()'|'(?=\))/g, "$1\\'");
```

The regex matches either `('` or `'` if it is followed by `)` (without actually matching that). At the same time we "capture" the `(` if it is there. The `$1` in the replacement string puts the `(` back in place if it was captured, and then simply writes out `\'`. There is no need to write the `)` back. Because we used a lookahead, it was never part of the match.

Comment: The first recommendation worked pretty well. That's a good catch. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in one line without regex:

```
myText = myText.split("('").join("(\\'").split("')").join("\\')");
```